# React Native - Send event from Javascript to Native

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I have been following the steps in [this page](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-android.html) of the React Native documentation on how to hook up Native Modules.

The documentation discusses how it's possible to send event from Native code to Javascript, however I need to be able to send events in the other direction, i.e from Javascript to Native code. Is this possible to do with the DeviceEventEmitter?

My use case is the following, Native Module loads up a React Native bundle, which in this case is a Login page. The login details are entered and checked against an API and when the response has come back I need to be able to return the result from Javascript to the Native module so I can resolve the original Promise on the React Method.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: No, `DeviceEventEmitter` is not intended for native event handling. You most-likely need to expose a native method which can then be invoked from JS.  You could, perhaps, use the DeviceEventEmitter as part of resolving the JS-side promise, but more likely you would just provide a callback to your native module to dispatch (and resolve the promise on the JS side.) The question could be simplified to get more answers, as-is it has layers, is perhaps not answerable.

Answer (score -3):

You would already have solved this problem. If not then, 
You can define methods in Java which will be available to Javascript. Steps are covered in below document,
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-android.html

You can directly when invoke these methods from javascript when API response is received.